# What's the best Primary Key for a model with PersonAccounts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, person-accounts, data-model

My Data is coming from Service Cloud with Marketing Cloud Connect, and the Person Accounts are activated.

I want to create a Data Model with my 'PersonAccount Data Extension' (made with Account fields) and some Data Extensions populated with data coming from Custom Objects.
In Service Cloud, these Custom Objects are related to Account, via Lookups to Accounts.

As the All Contacts table has the Contact Id (003) shown as the Contact Key, it seems to be a bad idea to set the AccountId as a Primary Key in my Data Extension (or at least to match the Account Id with the Subscriber Key as I'll have duplicates in All Contacts).

So should I use PersonContactId as a Primary Key (and relating to Subscribers on Subscriber Key) and make my relations between 'Person Account Data Extension' and the other Data Extensions with Account Id ?
Or I have no choice than asking Service Cloud admins to add a lookup with ContactId for each Custom Object ? (or even create it by myself with SQL queries...) ?

Thank you for your inputs !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- PersonContactId as Subscriber Key ("relating to subscribers on...")
- PersonContactId as Primary Key.

The reasons are outlined below. Using AccountId instead, and injecting into Journey Builder WILL create unwanted duplicate contacts.

[Using Account Id from Salesforce as the Subscriber Key in Marketing Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330664/using-account-id-from-salesforce-as-the-subscriber-key-in-marketing-cloud/335424#335424)

[Clarification on Marketing Cloud Connect and Contact Count](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/373987/clarification-on-marketing-cloud-connect-and-contact-count/374016#374016)

- You can do your connections in the data model both ways.

Comment: Thank you very much Jonas, that's very clear !